# How to call TRichEdit methods inside delphi procedures

Tags: delphi, vcl, procedure, trichedit

I'm saluting everyone once again, of course, having another problem while coding.

I written the following snippet:

```
procedure add_text(text : String);
begin
  MsgBox.SetFocus;
  MsgBox.SelStart := MsgBox.GetTextLen;
  MsgBox.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
  MsgBox.SelText := time_stamp + ' ' + text + #13#10; //time_stamp is a function
end;
```

The problem is, how can I access those MsgBox's methods inside a procedure ? (program cannot be compiled due "undeclared undentifier MsgBox"

Note: Edit the question if it's not clear enough.
Note2: Also tried to use TChatForm.MsgBox / ChatForm.MsgBox but still unsuccessfull..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call procedure with your Richedit as Parameter:

```
procedure add_text(MsgBox:TRichedit;const text : String);
begin
  MsgBox.SetFocus;
  MsgBox.SelStart := MsgBox.GetTextLen;
  MsgBox.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
  MsgBox.SelText := time_stamp + ' ' + text + #13#10; //time_stamp is a function
end;
```

Comment: bummy how do you know MsgBox is a TRichEdit? :o

Comment: @jachguate , help me? That's what the questions was about, where is the mistake ...

Comment: @Bummy, there's no mistake, just the question lacks context and you may know that because you know more than the casual reader about the problem. MsgBox sounds like a TMessageBox instance (or something like that) to me, but not a TRichEdit instance, and the question doesn't state it is.